# wooocoomerce cart discount based on products and categories

Tags: php, woocommerce, e-commerce

Can't seem to find a way to make this woocommerce cart discount, I have tried all the available plugins, paid and free but non have the options I need so I am trying to learn how to add a custom discount into the functions file of wordpress.

scenario:

product a price: 400
product RRRR: 10
product ZZZZ: 10

Buy product A

and

24 product RRRR

and 48 product ZZZZ

get $200 off category "cat999"

** Product RRRR and ZZZZ are part of "cat999"

Thank you for any advise

using the latest wp 4.1 
and WC 2.2.10

Comment: So, you say, if i buy product (A), i can get a discount in products (B) and (C), but (B) and (C) must being in same category as (A) ?

Comment: buy the magazine display AND 24 sport magazines AND 48 food magazines get $200 on magazines. All three things must be exactly there for the discount to be applied and although sport and food magazines are part of the general magazine category the buy has to add EXTRA magazine products to get the discount so it would look something like this

Comment: 1 magazine stand ------ $400  24 sport magazines --- $240   48 food magazines $480 Subtotal= $1,100   Discount= $0  Total= 1,100

Comment: 1 magazine stand ------ $400 48 sport magazines --- $480   96 food magazines $960   10 decoration magazines --- $100 Subtotal= $1940 Discount= $200 Total= 1,740      The discount was only applied on any magazines added after the 48 sport magazines and 72 food magazines anything less than that 48 and 72 no discount